# Pulling SQL Script from Database Using pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssms, pyodbc

I'm relatively new to databases, so this question may have a simple answer (I've been searching for hours).

I want to write a Python script that pulls the SQL Code stored in SQL Server Management Studio.  I can successfully connect to the database using pyodbc and run queries against the database tables, but I would like to be able to pull, for example, the SQL code stored in a procedure, function, view, etc. without running it.

This seems like something that would be relatively simple. I know it can be done in Powershell, but I would prefer to use Python. Is there some sort of module or pyodbc hack that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sp_helptext` command in SQL Server, which will give you the SQL Server object source code line by line:

```
stored_proc_text = ""

res = cursor.execute('sp_helptext my_stored_procedure')

for row in res:
    stored_proc_text += row[0]

print(stored_proc_text)
```

Good luck!

Comment: This works great!  I have some `SET` and `USE` statements at the head of some of the SQL scripts that  sp_helptext doesn't seem to pull when running cursor.execute(). Do you happen to know what that area is called and how I can pull those statements using sp_helptext?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a way. This method pulls the actual procedure itself, after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. The other statements before that are just run-time statements that aren't permanently stored in the database.